# Get permission bits string on Linux/Perl?

Tags: linux, perl, file-permissions

I want to write a shell / Perl script which can check if a file has particular permission bits set.

For example I want to check if a file has permissions like

```
drwxr-s---
```

When I use the `stat` function in Perl, it gives me a decimal number.
Is there a way I can get the exact string like above in my perl script and compare it?
If not - is there a way to convert that string into a number and then compare?

Comment: See `man 2 stat` and `perldoc -f -X`

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot : Not really. Here I want to see if the file has all the permission bits that I mentioned. The other questions is just to check the s bit of owner. Apologies for confusion though.

Comment: Don't think of what Perl returns as a decimal number. Think of it as an octal set of permissions. You can use _bit math_ to check whether a particular permission is set. You can also use Perl's [file tests](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html) to check permission too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just convert your decimial number to binary form and use binary AND or XOR?

This code gives you binary permissions:

```
printf '%b', (stat 'filename.txt')[2] & 07777;
```

For example, -rw-r----- binary form will be 110100000.

Comment: Ya that works too, but I want to retrieve the string value of permissions as is. Is that possible?

Comment: @user2780224, yep. There's a function format_perms() taking decimal form and giving you the string you want.

Answer (score 0):

I somehow got the number needed to compare against and this is what I used to get the required answer -

```
my $mode = (stat('$file'))[2];
printf("permissions are %04o\n", $mode & 07777);
```

and this worked for me!!